Porting old log4cxx code: synchronized missing
I have httpd server and I have used log4cxx for logging. But the log4cxx I was using was very old and I need to upgrade it now. When I tried to do it, I saw so many  files have been removed.
For example synchronized.h and synchronized.cpp are removed in v1.1.0 but present in v0.10.0.
In my code I used synchronized like this
synchronized sync(mutex);

But now as synchronized.h and .cpp are removed I can't use the same code.

The synchronized.{cpp,h} files were removed in this commit.
You should replace all uses of the previous Mutex class with the C++ std::mutex and synchronized with std::lock_guard. But you are free to take your mutex implementation from Boost or other sources as well.

Please tell me how did you find this. I have long way to go. Need to modify so many classes.

I just looked at the commit history of the project for the commit that removed those files.
